# Passing Multiple Variables to PHP page Using Javascript $.post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I am trying to pass multiple variables to a php page using JavaScript. Currently the JavaScript code posts a variable 'page' to fetch_pages.php. I would like to post another variable 'currentpage' to it as well. The javaScript code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var track_click = 0; //track user click on "load more" button, righ now it is 0 click
var total_pages = <? php echo $total_pages; ?> ;
$('#results').load("/include/fetch_pages.php", {
    'page': track_click
}, function() {
    track_click++;
}); //initial data to load
$(".load_more").click(function(e) { //user clicks on button
    $(this).hide(); //hide load more button on click
    $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image
    if (track_click <= total_pages) //make sure user clicks are still less than total pages
    {
        //post page number and load returned data into result element
        $.post('/include/fetch_pages.php', {
            'page': track_click
        }, function(data) {
            $(".load_more").show(); //bring back load more button
            $("#results").append(data); //append data received from server
            //hide loading image
            $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received
            track_click++; //user click increment on load button
        }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError); //alert any HTTP error
            $(".load_more").show(); //bring back load more button
            $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received
        });
        if (track_click >= total_pages - 1) {
            //reached end of the page yet? disable load button
            $(".load_more").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }
});
```

});

I assume I will need to add another variable to the JavaScript code like:

```
var currentpage = 'index.php'
```

and then post it with the 'page' variable but I am new to Javascript and am unsure how to do it.

fetch_pages.php currently shows:

```
$page_number = filter_var($_POST["page"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

and I also assume i will have to add variable to it like:

```
$currentpage = $_POST["currentpage "];
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `var url; $.post(url, ...)`?

Comment: [RT(F)M](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery, you can add multiple values to the POST like this:

```
$.post('/include/fetch_pages.php',{'page': track_click, 'currentpage' : 'foo'}, function(data) {
    #do stuff
}
```

In your case you want to pass the current page in. The most common way to do this is via `window.location.pathname`. If you were at `www.example.com/foo/bar.php` then `window.location.pathname` would be equal to `foo/bar.php`, which I assume is what you want.

So to fully answer your question, you would want code like this:

```
$.post('/include/fetch_pages.php',{'page': track_click, 'currentpage' : window.location.pathname}, function(data) { /* ... */ }
```

Or, if you only want the name of the current file (such as `bar.php`) without the directories in front, you can do this:

```
$.post('/include/fetch_pages.php',{'page': track_click, 'currentpage' : window.location.pathname.split( '/' ).slice(-1)[0]}, function(data) { /* ... */ }
```

Then in your PHP file you can access this quite simply:

```
$curr_page = $_POST['currentpage'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
{'page':track_click}
```

to

```
{'page':track_click,'anotherVar':'whatever'}
```